# Linux Mint 17 could not boot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, linux-mint

I have a sony external hard drive. In that i created dev/sdc1/ (NTFS) for windows8.1 clone image via clonezilla.

```
dev/sdc2 (NTFS)
dev/sdc3 (NTFS)
```

then i deleted sdc2 and then created root/ , home/ and swap file. Then i putted bootloader in root/ (sdc2 ext4 /). After install when i choose to boot from external hard drive. A message show up on screen saying couldn't find operating system. Press ctrl+Alt+dlt. Whats wrong? Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things could have gone wrong. First, **I'm not sure that you can boot Windows off of external hard drives**. If you restored a cloned image, and then installed bootloader (GRUB) to the root partition (sdc2), this means that Windows bootloader wasn't overwritten and is still active. Bootloader has to be installed to the hard drive itself (sdc) so that it adds its entries to the MBR. Another thing that might be causing this mess is if you have GPT partition scheme because of restored Windows 8 image. That's the best answer I can give, someone else might know better...